# using an asp.net VB variable in javascript animate

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql

I am calling a list of records from my sql database then I write them to a dynamic table. During this I have a variable(CountRecord) that increments every time I add a new element to the table. I was wondering if it was possible to call CountRecord from my .js file and change my

```
$("#SubFirst").animate({height:525},"slow");
```

to something like

```
$("#SubFirst").animate({height:"<%=CountRecord%>*30px"},"slow");
```

I am guessing that the variable doesn't cross over different files. So I don't even know if this is possible. If anyone knows of a different way to do this I am willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Just wondering @SLaks but what was the edit? Was it just the format or font?

Comment: Once a new data is inserted, the CountRecord is increasing in the server side. You can create a public property in the code behind and use it like $("#SubFirst").animate({height:"<%=CountRecord%>*30px"},"slow");

Comment: @TimG: You should indent code with four spaces.

Comment: @Tariqulazam Do I just need to create a function and have the animate within it? If so when do I call it? I am new to this so if you could explain it almost step by step that would be great!

Comment: Post your HTML and VB.NET Code as it will give us a better understanding of your approach.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/J2LCa/1/ The results section is worthless. I can put all of my html/cs/js code if necessary. I was just trying to give you the sections that pertain to my question. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're updating your count variable server side, then your approach is correct, all for one small syntax error.

```
var heightToSet = "<%=CountRecord %>" * 30; 
$("#SubFirst").animate({height: heightToSet + "px"},"slow");
```

**EDIT**

Answer in here for clarity,

I believe the offending line should be

```
<a onclick=" <%dim NumClicked=0 dim CountRecord =20 if NumClicked =0 then%> 
$('#SubFirst').animate({height:'<%=CountRecord%>'*30 + 'px'},'slow'); 
<%NumClicked=NumClicked+1 else %>$('#SubFirst').animate({height:525px},'slow'); 
<%NumClicked=0 end if%>" id="first" overflow: "hidden">People</a>
```

Comment: For some reason it isn't changing the height of the div. The object still expands the width correctly but the height doesn't change at all. When I write the variable heightToSet to the console I get NaN(not a number) Any idea why?

Comment: you'd have to show me the code that you're using. I set up a test case and demonstrated that this worked before submitting. (you're misake was including the 'px' in your multiplication by the way, I attempted to split the numeric and string operations)

Comment: just spotted your fiddle. the obtrusive js is rather unpleasant. however, the solution is 

<a onclick="          
    <%dim NumClicked=0
    dim CountRecord =20
    if NumClicked =0 then%>
    $('#SubFirst').animate({height:'<%=CountRecord%>'*30 + 'px'},'slow');
    <%NumClicked=NumClicked+1
    else
    %>$('#SubFirst').animate({height:525px},'slow');
    <%NumClicked=0
    end if%>"        
        id="first" overflow: "hidden">People</a>

Comment: I have replaced your internal double quotes with singles and edited the js slightly. I must admit, reading that is rather unpleasant.

Comment: That would be bcause when you access CountRecord in your onclick event, it's yet to be incremented at all. Rather than this approach, would it not be better to access the required height from jQuery?

Comment: Thank you ben for sticking with this! The onclick part works but the CountRecord doesn't increase. And the separate javascript(heightToSet) still doesn't register as a number when I try to set it to the CountRecord * 30. I am stuck now on how to get the onclick part to have the correct CountRecord. I am currently trying to have COUNT(ID) in my sql statement but for some reason that is only giving me like one record.

Comment: Are you suggesting having trying to adjust the height in the separate js file? I think I might try to copy the part where CountRecord increments and have that cycle through before the onclick part. Then reset the variables so it can create the table after onclick

Comment: YEAH it worked!!!! I was able to scroll through it before hand and then reset variables and create the table!!!!!! Thank you SO much @Ben Emery for helping me realize the obvious(CountRecord would be 0 because it hasn't been incremented yet.) And thanks for dealing with the terrible inline js!:)